# What type of filter is the "filter" command

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I'm using MATLAB's `filter` function to create a moving average of a line graph. My question is, what kind of filter is? Low pass? High pass? etc...

I'm a sophomore electrical engineer so this kind of question is of particular interest to me.

I'm graphing the average temperature in January.

```
temperature = filter(ones(1,3)/3,1,janTemp);
plot(days,temperature);
```

where `janTemp` is the 1 column vector with the temperatures and `days` is the list of days in a vector.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to call `filter`?  The short answer is that the type of filter depends on the kernel coefficients provided in the first two arguments.  See the docs for `butter`, for example, to create a filter you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` doesn't *create* a filter; it *applies* a filter to a signal:

> FILTER One-dimensional digital filter. 
>       Y = FILTER(B,A,X) filters the data in vector X with the
>       filter described by vectors A and B to create the filtered
>       data Y.

The filter will be low-pass, high-pass etc depending on the coefficient vectors `A`, `B`. These vectors contain the coefficients of the difference equation defining the filter:

> a(1)*y(n) = b(1)*x(n) + b(2)*x(n-1) + ... + b(nb+1)*x(n-nb) 
>                             - a(2)*y(n-1) - ... - a(na+1)*y(n-na)

Equivalently, `A` and `B` define the numerator and denominator polynomials of the filter's transfer function, H(z).

In your case, with `B = [1 1 1]` and `A = 1`,  it will be a low-pass FIR filter, i.e. a moving  average, as you indicate in your question.

See [`filter`'s documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) or type `help filter` for details.

Comment: how does A and B describe the filter? How would I know that it's low pass from those values?

Comment: @codedude `A` and `B` are the coefficients of the difference equation defining the filter. Alternatively, they define the numerator and denominator polynomials of the filter's transfer function, H(z)

Comment: Just a nitpick: there's more than just low- or high-pass from FIR and IIR filters. band-pass, band-stop, notch, etc.

Comment: @chappjc True. Corrected

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to visualize the frequency response of a filter is with [`freqz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html).

```
freqz([1 1 1]/3,1)
```

[image]

This filter attenuates high frequencies, but by no means very well.

Consider a 5-tap [Butterworth](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html) FIR filter:

```
freqz(butter(5,0.5,'low'),1)
```

[image]

See also [`fvtool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fvtool.html), the Filter Visualization Tool (FVTool).

Answer (score 1):

Moving average is usually an example of low pass filter. See more information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

In general you can learn more about filters in matlab at http://www.mathworks.com/tagteam/55876_digfilt.pdf.